# Is there a python function or code that can rearrange(format) dataframe just like i showed?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need help formatting my datasets in python, it looks like this

| l1 | A1 | B1 | A2 | B2 | A3 | B3 | A4 | B4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 |
| 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | NAN | 19 |
| 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 |

I need to format it to look like this.....

| l1 | A1 | B1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 12 | 6 | 7 |
| 20 | 8 | 9 |
| 30 | 10 | 11 |
| 40 | 12 | 13 |

please any python function that can rearrange this table will be highly appreciated.
Thank you as I await your positive response

Comment: can you elaborate on the logic, is the provided output an approximate example or the real explicit output?

Comment: Transpose in steps ? Looks to me..? That would be my first guess / try. Starting from aswell . What's your logic? Why are you wanting this ? Can you elaborate in your post . Theres also reshape.

Comment: Do I need to change the data frame or can I create another one? I can only create what is expected based on this data frame. And basically most of it is not made on pandas, it is possible that there is not enough experience in it. It seems to me that I have understood the logic on the basis of which such values are obtained.

Comment: Please follow - Stack Overflow posting etiquette: - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
-  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

The logic is not fully clear on the first column and why part of the data gets missing, but it looks like you need to use [`pandas.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
(pd
 .wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['A', 'B'], i='l1', j='x')
 .droplevel('x')
 .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
    l1    A   B
0    1    2   3
1   12   13  14
2   20   21  22
3    1    6   7
4   12   15  16
5   20   23  24
6    1    8   9
7   12   17  18
8   20   25  26
9    1   10  11
10  12  NAN  19
11  20   27  28
```

Answer (score 0):

First, in order for the column 'A4' to be of the int type, you need to replace 'MAN' with a number and set the column type to int.
In my understanding, the logic is as follows. For the values 'l1', the entire column is taken, where the values and we begin to add to the previous 'l1', the last value 'A1'.

"A" are even numbers, "B" odd even numbers taken from the zero line. Or read the first letter in the column name.To continue columns 'A1', 'B1' you need to add the first value 'A1'. Maybe someone will make it more beautiful on pandas.

```
df = df.replace('NAN', 777)
df['A4'] = df['A4'].astype(int)

a = [df[i][0] for i in df.columns if i[0] == 'A']
b = [df[i][0] for i in df.columns if i[0] == 'B']

l = df['l1'].to_list()
[l.append(l[i] + a[-1]) for i in range(2, 4)]#fill in the missing column data 'l1'

df = pd.DataFrame([l, a, b])
df = df.T
df = df.set_axis(['l1', 'A1', 'B1'], axis=1, inplace=False)
df.loc[4, ['A1', 'B1']] = (df['A1'][3] + df['A1'][0]), (df['B1'][3] + df['A1'][0])#fill in the missing columns data 'A1' and 'B1'
```

Output

```
   l1  A1  B1
0   1   2   3
1  12   6   7
2  20   8   9
3  30  10  11
4  40  12  13
```